# Finding min, max and average of elements in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to find the smallest and largest numbers, stored as doubles, in an Array. This is the array:

```
double[] heightArray = {1.4,1.9,1.31,1.2};
```

In attempting to find the smallest and largest element, I have used the following method:

```
public static void studentHeights(double[] heightArray) {
    double total = 0;
    double average;
    double maximum = 0;
    double minimum = 0;

    for (int loop = 0; loop < heightArray.length; loop++) {
        System.out.println(heightArray[loop]);
        total += heightArray[loop];
        if (heightArray[loop] > maximum) {
            maximum = heightArray[loop];
        }
        if (heightArray[loop] < minimum) {
            minimum = heightArray[loop];
        }

    }
    average = total / heightArray.length;
    System.out.println("The maximum height is: " + maximum);
    System.out.println("The minimum height is: " + minimum);
    System.out.println("The average height is: " + average);

}
```

The console outputs:

```
1.4
1.9
1.31
1.2
The maximum height is: 1.9
The minimum height is: 0.0
The average height is: 1.4525
```

The largest (maximum) element is correct, as is the average. However, the smallest (minimum) element is being recorded as `0.0`. This must be because none of the elements are less than 0, but I can't think how I can calculate the smallest element another way.

Comment: you should initialize `max` with `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `min` with `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: I would start by initializing the min and the max to the value of the first element rather than 0. Technically, an empty list has no min or max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your minimum to be something very large instead of 0

```
double minimum = 0;
```

Such as the largest possible value, conveniently [defined in a constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

```
double minimum = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

You may want to use the MIN_VALUE when initializing the maximum value

```
double maximum = Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

Comment: Actually the max search has exactly the same problem, it just does not show up with this test case.

Comment: CAUTION: using [Double.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) is wrong here (it is `> 0.0`). This will also yield wrong values if there are acutally only infinities in the array (less likely, but still....).

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize the minimum variable with the first element of the array instead of the value 0,

for example

```
double minimum = heightArray[0];
```

If there are negative numbers in the array your maximum logic will not work as excepted, consider initialize the maximum variable also

```
double maximum = heightArray[0];
```

Comment: Why just the minimum? max only works because there is an element >0 in the array.

Comment: Taking care that the array is nonempty, of course. This solution is nice because it can be extended even for non-`double` types which might not have easily accessible minima and maxima.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in an alternative method you can use [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) and [`Collections.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-) for this task:

```
List<Double> lst = Arrays.asList(heightArray); // array to list
System.out.println(Collections.min(lst)); // print max value
System.out.println(Collections.max(lst)); // print min value
System.out.println(lst.stream().mapToDouble(e->e.doubleValue()).average().getAsDouble()); //average
```

Why [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) or [`Collections.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-) ? Because it can be used in any type of primitive or Wrapper Class Objects.

**Links:**

- [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
- [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: I like that answer but he need the average of the array also

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 be more easier, you have multiple choices to go with

**Option 1**

```
double max = Arrays.stream(heightArray).max().getAsDouble();
double min = Arrays.stream(heightArray).min().getAsDouble();
double avg = Arrays.stream(heightArray).average().getAsDouble();
```

---

**Option 2**

You can use [DoubleStream.of(double... values)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#of-double...-)

```
double max = DoubleStream.of(heightArray).max().getAsDouble();
double min = DoubleStream.of(heightArray).min().getAsDouble();
double avg = DoubleStream.of(heightArray).average().getAsDouble();
```

---

**Option 3**

You can use [DoubleSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html)

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = DoubleStream.of(heightArray).summaryStatistics();

double min = stats.getMin();
double max = stats.getMax();
double avg = stats.getAverage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just **`sort()`** your array:

```
// Initialize unsorted double array.
double HeightsArray[] = {1.4, 1.9, 1.31, 1.2};

// Sorting the array.
Arrays.sort(HeightsArray);

System.out.println("Smallest number: " + HeightsArray[0]);
System.out.println("Largest number: " + HeightsArray[HeightsArray.length - 1]);
```

Will output:

```
Smallest number: 1.2
Largest number: 1.9
```

Comment: This would raise the run time from O(n) to at least O(n log n). Not a good idea.

Comment: You mean because of the sort function? or because he'd have to iterate for the average anyways?

Comment: Because of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you've already identified, is that you want to start your iteration with a value larger than any other value in your array. Ideally, we would start with the largest value available to store in a `double`. Fortunately, we have just such a value: [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

Likewise, you could change your maximum search to start with `- Double.MAX_VALUE` so that your function continues working if passed a list of entirely negative numbers.

Comment: CAUTION: using [Double.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) is wrong here (it is > 0.0). A bit less problematic, but  `Double.MAX` is also not the largest possible `double` as it is smaller than `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: Ah, another case of the Java library being named by monkeys. *Of course* a value called `MIN_VALUE` would not actually be the minimum value. Nonetheless, thanks for the note :)